# Drupal 8: How to print node__field values in hook_views_query_alter function?

Tags: drupal-views, drupal-8

i try to print node field values in the hook_views_query_alter function.
I would add a new condition with this function

```
    function mymodule_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
        if ($view->id() == 'my_view' && $view->current_display == "block_1") {
            $query->addWhere(
            $options['group'],
            db_and()
            ->condition('node__field_myfield.field_myfield', 'myvalue', '=')
            );          
      }
    }
```

in this case "myvalue" should be a value from node field